# Highlighting duplicates over multiple rows using conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a Google spreadsheet to organise a seating plan. I've laid out the page with 11 separated smaller tables in a kind of grid format (for easier reading, as you can see it all without scrolling).  Like this:

```
      Table 1       |      Table 2       |      Table 3       |
 Seat | Name | Diet | Seat | Name | Diet | Seat | Name | Diet |
    1 |      |      |    1 |      |      |    1 |      |      |
    2 |      |      |    2 |      |      |    2 |      |      |
```

I'm trying to create a conditional format to highlight cells where a name appears more than once.

So I created a conditional format with a custom formula as follows (the range covers the all tables):

```
COUNTIF($A$1:$O$42, A1)>1;
```

and I set the range to only the Name cells on the page.

However when I purposely set a duplicate the cells are not highlighted.

I thought that maybe my formula was wrong, so I put into a cell and pointed it at a duplicate cell and it returned TRUE.

So I'm at a loss a how to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula applied to range A3:O

`=AND(ISTEXT(A3),COUNTIF($A$3:$O$42, A3)>1)`

Example sheet is here: https://goo.gl/hChZbt

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me, however, selecting the whole page also highlighted cells in the Diet column as well as all the table headers. 

When I tried to apply the conditional formatting to only the Name cells I got an Invalid Formula error.  Why would changing the range do that?

As it stands, I've had to leave it applied to the whole page and create a second conditional format that removes the highlight on the diet column and table headers

Comment: I've changed the range on the formula sheet back to A:O and used the formula =AND(ISTEXT(A1),arrayformula(A1<>{"seat","Name","Diet"}),COUNTIF($A$1:$O$42, A1)>1)

Comment: I think the invalid error you were getting is because my previous formula started at row 3 (to avoid the values in row 2) so cannot be applied to a whole column starting at row 1.  The revised formula caters for the values in row 2 by using an arrayformula instead though.